# How do I start a new line in <textarea>

Tags: html

Here is my code:

```
<textarea name='awesome'><?php
                                    if(session::exists('home')) {
                                        echo Session::flash('home') . '       ';
                                    }
                                    if($user->hasPermission('admin')) {
                                        echo 'You are an administrator!';
                                    }
                                    if(isset($_SESSION['bodycontentmessage'])){
                                        echo $_SESSION['bodycontentmessage'];
                                    }
                                    $_SESSION['bodycontentmessage'] = "";
                                  ?></textarea>
```

How do I make it so that each if statement variable produces a new line within this textarea?
For example if I ran it like it is now, it would output inside the textarea:

You are an administrator!Successfully logged in!

However I want it to say:

You are an administrator!

Successfully logged in!

Any idea how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('textarea').html('Hello'+"\r\n"+'There');
```

```css
textarea{width:100%;height:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

In your PHP, do the same thing:

> `echo 'You are ' ."\r\n". 'an administrator!';`

Note that if you later post the data into a back-end database, you might need to programmatically search/replace the `\r\n` with `<br>` before inserting into the DB, so that future rendering will render correctly.

Also note the use of double-quotes around the `\r\n`. Sometimes this matters.

Comment: how would I implement this into my code? p.s ive never used javascript before

Comment: where do I insert this: $('textarea').html('Hello'+"\r\n"+'There');
textarea{width:100%;height:100px;}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>

Comment: You don't -- that was to demonstrate how it works. Not possible to demo PHP in an SO demo. However, I re-code it below with PHP -- just do the PHP part.  `echo "Hello" ."\r\n". " there"`

Answer (score 0):

In html, use
\n
or \r\n.

For example,

```
<textarea>Hello,\r\nWorld!</textarea>
```

In some frameworks like php or jsp,

you can replace \r\n with your own markup

and replace it with \r\n again using script.

Usually I use @br@ in jsp,

replace it with \r\n again in html.

So it flows like below

```
textarea:Hello,\r\nWorld! -> request to server
-> jsp:"Hello,\r\nWorld!".replaceAll( "\\r", "" ).replaceAll( "\\n", "@br@" );
-> do something

jsp:"Hello,@br@World!" -> response to client
-> js:"Hello,@br@World!".replace( /@br@/g, "\r\n" );
-> textarea:Hello,\r\nWorld!
```

Try it.

If it doesn't work,

let me know.

---

**Edit**

I don't know your whole html code but it may seem like below

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea name="awesome">Hello,\r\nWorld!</textarea>
        <script>
            var textarea = document.getElementsByName( "awesome" )[0];
            textarea.value = textarea.value.replace( /\\r\\n/g, "\r\n" );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With that script part, text in textarea will be chaned as you want.

Without it, it just Hello,\r\nWorld!.

Comment: then it just says "Hello,\r\nWorld!" in the textarea?

Comment: It is Just an example.  You should use script to replace it.

Comment: where do I copy this into? ive never used javascript before

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your textarea has the right CSS.

```
textarea {
    white-space:pre;
}
```

Then split your php into multiple lines with a newline character between after each if statement.

```
<textarea name='awesome'><?php
    if(session::exists('home')) {
        echo Session::flash('home')."\n";
    }
    if($user->hasPermission('admin')) {
        echo "You are an administrator!\n";
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['bodycontentmessage'])){
        echo $_SESSION['bodycontentmessage']."\n";
    }
    $_SESSION['bodycontentmessage'] = "";
?></textarea>
```

Comment: doesnt work, just shows: You are an administrator!\n\n

Comment: Looks like it might be a PHP quirk, try changing the single quotes to double quotes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<textarea name='awesome'>
<?php
    if(session::exists('home')) {
        echo Session::flash('home') . '       ';
    }
    if($user->hasPermission('admin')) {
        echo 'You are an administrator!' ."\r\n";
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['bodycontentmessage'])){
        echo $_SESSION['bodycontentmessage'] ."\r\n";
    }
    $_SESSION['bodycontentmessage'] = "" ."\r\n";
?>
</textarea>
```